# ImageMagick: PDF to PNG nodejs without using files?

Tags: node.js, pdf, imagemagick

I need to create an endpoint to render a pdf to an image in nodejs and after trying different approaches imagemagick/ghostscript seem to be the best option.

However they expect files as input and output.

Is there a way to only work in memory/variables instead of messing with filesystem (performance/resources is a concern here)?

The ideal scenario is to provide a pdf as base64 string to imagemagick and get an image in base64 string as well.

But since imagemagick is a command line tool I have no idea how to accomplish that and if it's possible at all? Maybe there is a way to hook into the streaming process so I could override where the data goes (like somehow overriding stdin/stdout of imagemagick process or whatever to accumulate the data in a variable instead of sending it to a file)

Or if it's a dead-end, what are alternatives to render pdf to png in node without using files? 
Tried pdf.js which sort of does it but it appeared to be very unreliable in node for this.

Any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ImageMagick command line, you can convert base64 files using the INLINE: mechanism.  For example:

```
convert 'inline:data:image/gif;base64,
      R0lGODlhIAAgAPIEAAAAAB6Q/76+vvXes////wAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAA
      AAAgACAAAAOBWLrc/jDKCYG1NBcwegeaxHkeGD4j+Z1OWl4Yu6mAYAu1ebpwL/OE
      YCDA0YWAQuJqRwsSeEyaRTUwTlxUqjUymmZpmeI3u62Mv+XWmUzBrpeit7YtB1/r
      pTAefv942UcXVX9+MjNVfheGCl18i4ddjwwpPjEslFKDUWeRGj2fnw0JADs=
    '  b64_noseguy.gif
```

or to pipe the output to some other tool:

```
convert 'inline:data:image/gif;base64,
      R0lGODlhIAAgAPIEAAAAAB6Q/76+vvXes////wAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAA
      AAAgACAAAAOBWLrc/jDKCYG1NBcwegeaxHkeGD4j+Z1OWl4Yu6mAYAu1ebpwL/OE
      YCDA0YWAQuJqRwsSeEyaRTUwTlxUqjUymmZpmeI3u62Mv+XWmUzBrpeit7YtB1/r
      pTAefv942UcXVX9+MjNVfheGCl18i4ddjwwpPjEslFKDUWeRGj2fnw0JADs=
    '  GIF:- | some_other_tool - ...
```

Produces:

[image]

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#inline

ADDITION:

If you want to read one base64 format and write to a variable holding a different base64 form, you can do that with INLINE: in ImageMagick as follows:

Read base64 gif and convert to base64 jpg and save to a variable:

```
base64jpg=$(convert 'inline:data:image/gif;base64,
R0lGODlhIAAgAPIEAAAAAB6Q/76+vvXes////wAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAA
AAAgACAAAAOBWLrc/jDKCYG1NBcwegeaxHkeGD4j+Z1OWl4Yu6mAYAu1ebpwL/OE
YCDA0YWAQuJqRwsSeEyaRTUwTlxUqjUymmZpmeI3u62Mv+XWmUzBrpeit7YtB1/r
pTAefv942UcXVX9+MjNVfheGCl18i4ddjwwpPjEslFKDUWeRGj2fnw0JADs=
' INLINE:JPG:-)
```

Now read the base64 jpg and convert to PNG:

```
convert inline:$base64jpg noseguy_b64.png
```

[image]

But JPG does not support transparency, so it is lost when saving to JPG. Thus the background now is black in place of the original transparent.

ADDITION 2:

Convert the GIF to base64 PDF and then convert that to PNG works fine for me.

```
base64pdf=$(convert 'inline:data:image/gif;base64,
R0lGODlhIAAgAPIEAAAAAB6Q/76+vvXes////wAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEAAAUALAAA
AAAgACAAAAOBWLrc/jDKCYG1NBcwegeaxHkeGD4j+Z1OWl4Yu6mAYAu1ebpwL/OE
YCDA0YWAQuJqRwsSeEyaRTUwTlxUqjUymmZpmeI3u62Mv+XWmUzBrpeit7YtB1/r
pTAefv942UcXVX9+MjNVfheGCl18i4ddjwwpPjEslFKDUWeRGj2fnw0JADs=
' INLINE:PDF:-)

convert inline:$base64pdf noseguy_b64.png
```

[image]

Comment: thanks! I guess that solves it for input. I guess output still goes to a file - is there any way to somehow write it to a variable as well?

Comment: You can pipe the output from ImageMagick to some other tool, if it accepts input from stdin. Replace `b64_noseguy.gif` with `GIF:-` in my command in my answer.

Comment: ok, thanks for the update - I'm trying to check their docs, but I'm not that proficient with ImageMagick - could you show an example of how to create a jpeg and send it to variable?

Comment: You cannot send an image to a variable unless you convert it to base64. My suggestion above was to pipe the image from the above command from ImageMagick after reading the base64 and convert to GIF (or any other format such as JPG) so that some other tool you want to use will read stdin from the pipe.  If you want JPG for output from my command above, just change `GIF:- | ...` to `JPG:- | ...`

Comment: See my ADDITION in my answer for converting from one base64 format to another and save it as a variable.

Comment: can't quite see the addition. I'm trying to figure out how to make use of this 'some_other_tool' part so I can capture the result

Comment: It got lost. I posted it again.

Comment: thanks! I see now. This works with images but when I try with PDF which is my initial question, it fails with inline:data approach - I guess the problem is that pdf is handled by ghostscript internally which throws errors here saying "the file has been damaged".

Comment: Yes, ImageMagick needs Ghostscript to process PDF files. Using base64 PDF works for me. See my ADDITION 2 to my answer.

Comment: thanks - might be something with my base64 string then

Answer (score 4):

[sharp](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/) can do this. It uses [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) for PDF rendering, rather than shelling out to Ghostscript, so you can do everything in process and without touching the filesystem. It'll render PDFs progressively too, so memory use stays low.

The difficulty you'll have is that poppler is GPL, so the binaries that sharp ships don't include it. You'll need to [install a system version](https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install#custom-libvips) of [libvips](https://libvips.github.io/libvips/) (the underlying image processing library that sharp uses) that includes PDF support. You'll also need to be aware that having a GPL library linked into your node program makes your code GPL too. This means if you plan to sell your program, you'll have to give away the source. Selling access to your program is fine, of course.

Imagemagick is a great tool, but it will process PDFs via ghostscript using a set of large temporary files.

Comment: thanks! That's a bummer about Ghostscript. Trying to figure out how to compile sharp together now. Wondering if you might have any working example that you are comfortable to share?

Comment: You just install a system libvips, then `npm install sharp` and it'll use the system one. The system libvips on Ubuntu, for example, includes pdfload, so just `apt install libvips-dev`. You can check if your libvips supports PDF load by entering `vips pdfload` at the CLI.

Comment: I'm a noob here - no problem to install it on my system but have no idea how to do it in node environment (moreover I'm using firebase functions which removes some degree of freedom). Will try to figure that out and get back here - this might be the correct answer after all since Ghostscript uses files anyways as you've already mentioned.

Comment: It depends on your platform (Heroku, AWS, Debian, etc.), you'd need to give more information. The sharp issue tracker is a good place to ask for help.